# ProcessCmdKey() or OnKeyDown()

Tags: c#

Should we override ProcessCmdKey() or OnKeyDown() for handling key press events like Up Arrow press on a Form.

Answer (score 1):

OnKeyDown should do the trick and is best practice by my knowledge.